# How should I care for this Succulent?

Tags: identification, plant-care, succulents, aloe

I bought this plant over two weeks ago. What is its name? How should I take care of it?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a variety of [Haworthia](http://haworthia.org/), a succulent plant. Most of the members are from [South Africa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haworthia) and show a wide variety of shape and form.

When grown indoors they require full sun and well drained soil. Outdoors in warm climates they grow in full sun and in some shade.

The easiest way to propagate them is by offsets. Remove a leaf at the base, let dry and plant in sand.

Edit:  If you are growing a plant indoors then keep it indoors. It is not clear if you are moving the plant outside for short periods.  This will cause burn on parts of the plant.
This plant needs free draining soil which chicken grit or small particles of crushed quartz or perlite can provide.  Sand is not that good as it packs down or washes out.

Comment: I am growing this in normal soil used for common plants. Is it fine or should I mix some river sand with it ?

Comment: Also its leave's tips are drying out but news leaves are growing as well. I put them in sunlight almost 3 4 days a week for 4 to 6 hours